# Rails user can vote only in own order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rolify

This is my first post here so i want say Hello :)

I'm new to rails. In my app i use device + cancan + rolify. User with role :admin can manage all and this work very well, can create Order and vote up or down.
Next i want that, user with role :loc_adm can create order and could vote only in own orders. But here is my problem. 
When i try in my ability:

> 

```
def initialize(user)
user ||= User.new
if user.role? :admin
 can :manage, :all
else
 if user.role? :lok_adm 
  can :manage, Order, :user_id => user.id
  can :manage, Vote, :user_id => user.id
 end
 can :read, :all
end
```

User with role :lok_adm can voted not only in own order.
Below i send my models.

```
class Order
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :votes

class Vote
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :order

class User
 has_many :orders
 has_many :votes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not set what they can't manage.  Add

```
cannot :manage, :all
```

Above what they lok_adm can manage

You can also do

```
if condition
elsif another_condition
end
```

Rather than

```
if
else
  if
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks thats work, but now i have next problem, i have a link current_user where user go to user/show page and see all own order, but now i see flash message you are not authorized to access this page

Comment: So you need another can
`can :manage, User, :user_id => user.id`

Comment: When i try this i have error undefined method 'user_id' for # Class

Comment: Oops sorry, you want id.  I Shouldn't just copy things
`can :manage, User, :id => user.id`

Comment: Thanks :) now everythink its ok.